# add image on top to UILabel Swift

Tags: swift, uiimage, uilabel

i'm a new developer for ios. Is there a way where i could add a UIImageView on top of a UILabel ? I tried this but image is hidden from UILabel :(

```
 var imageTick:UIImage = UIImage(named: "Trash-icon.png")
    var imageView:UIImageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(self.bounds.size.width-50, self.bounds.size.height/2, 30, 30))
    imageView.image = imageTick
    labelTick.addSubview(imageView)
    self.addSubview(labelTick)
```

Answer (score 6):

These objects are stacked in the order in which they are added to their superview.

Instead of adding the labelTick subview to the imageView you want to add it to the super view before the image imageView:

```
var imageTick:UIImage = UIImage(named: "Trash-icon.png")
var imageView:UIImageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(self.bounds.size.width-50, self.bounds.size.height/2, 30, 30))
imageView.image = imageTick
self.addSubview(labelTick)
self.addSubview(imageView)
```

Alternatively you can also use insertSubview, to insert them above or below another one in the superview:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/insertSubview:aboveSubview: